# Is $\mathbb{L}^2$ space is a vector space?

Tags: real-analysis

Let us consider, $\mathbb{L}^2[0,2\pi]$ as the collection of square integrable functions $g:[0,2\pi]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{+}$. Is it true that, this $\mathbb{L}^2[0,2\pi]$space is a vector space? If yes, how to show this.

My attempt: Given a set I can check the closedness under the addition and multiplication. But for an arbitrary $\mathbb{L}^2$ space  I stuck at how to do that.

Comment: By $\mathbb{L}^2$, I assume you mean the square-integrable measurable functions on some domain; if so, then the proof that it's closed under sums is about one line of algebra and an application of Holder's inequality. Regardless of the underlying domain.

Comment: @T.Bongers. Thank you. I clarified the fast part of your comments in my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is often helpful to write down the precise statements. What does closedness under addition and multiplication mean in your case?

Well, closedness under multiplications just means that for $f\in L^2$, $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ you have $\lambda\cdot f\in L^2$ or $\int |\lambda f(x)|^2dx$ exists. That should be easy to conclude from that fact that $f$ itself is square-integrable using the fact the integral itself is linear.

For closedness under addition you take $f,g\in L^2$ and ask whether
$\int |f(x)+g(x)|^2 dx $ exists. This follows directly from the Minkowski inequality.